# Перехват html, генерируемого web-сервером перед отправкой

Tags: php, nginx, ruby, passenger

Здравствуйте!
Есть сервер на Linux - RubyonRails + Passenger + Nginx. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно перехватить html, генерируемый сервером, и модифицировать html? То есть нужно перехватить html перед отправкой, отдать в php скрипт, скрипт выполнит подмену текста и потом выполнить отправку.
Спасибо.

Comment: вероятно, с помощью буферизации вывода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Обратный прокси:** направляйте все запросы, поступающие на nginx, на PHP-скриптик (на отдельном вебсервере или прямо в nginx через php-fpm). Он должен будет отправлять поступивший ему запрос в неизменном* виде к реальному приложению посредством любого HTTP-клиента, например curl. Соответственно, из HTTP-клиента вы получите весь ответ: статус, заголовки и тело. Можете сделать с ними что угодно и отправить их в качестве собственного ответа после доработки.
- **Rack-прослойка (middleware)**: на уровне Ruby on Rails (а точнее Rack, на котором он построен) можно добавить  наружную функцию-прослойку, которая получит исходный запрос к приложению, передаст его глубже и получит ответ от приложения, но для отправки клиенту сможет сформировать собственный ответ (на Ruby, естественно; но из Ruby можно вызывать и другие программы, если нужно; а может, логику замены лучше написать на Ruby?).

  - [Пример Rack-прослойки](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Builder#use-instance_method)
  - [Rack-прослойки в Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html#configuring-middleware-stack)
- **Сделать по-нормальному:** сделать замену в исходном коде приложения на Ruby on Rails и не городить таких жутких костылей с перерасходом ресурсов.

---

* Хотя какие-то изменения внести вам всё-таки придётся и/или захочется, например про IP-адрес или наличие SSL. Во [вступлении RFC 7239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239#section-1) описан существующий де-факто стандарт общения с обратным прокси. Именно вступлении! Новый подход, предлагаемый этим RFC, я на практике пока не встречал.